# Proxy Error only when app is loaded in an iframe

Tags: reactjs, express, iframe, reverse-proxy

**Context**
I have a React app running on localhost:3000 and an express server running on localhost:5001. I also have this in my package.json: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5001",`

My React app calls `/api/init` when it first loads to grab some data from the server. After running both the react app and the server concurrently, everything works as expected when I navigate to localhost:3000 in my browser. The app makes a call to the server and I get the data I need.

**My problem:**
Fast forward many years, I now need to put my app inside an iframe to use it elsewhere. To recreate this, I made an html file that contains this code and then I opened the file so I can test what would happen in a browser.

```
<iframe src="https://localhost:3000"></iframe>
```

This loads the app, but the request to the server fails and I get this error:
`Proxy Error: could not proxy request /api/init from localhost:3000 to localhost:5001`

**Notes**

1. This same issue happens with the deployed version of the app and server, I wrote everything here using localhost so others can reproduce it easily. -edit: deployed version shouldn't depend on the proxy flag, please ignore this note as it is probably something else
2. I don't think anything is wrong with how I set up the proxy, because everything works fine when I open the app directly in a browser. The issue only happens when I make it the src of an iframe.
3. I read up on iframes, reverse-proxy, and this error I got and nothing helped. Everything I came across was about fixing the proxy for the react app (which I don't think is broken, see note 2).

If there is some security feature implemented in browsers that is specific to making the proxy request fail, please point me to some resources where I can read about it (I just wasn't able to find it myself).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this issue in the future. For me, it was because the server was trying to handle cookies, which it wasn't getting from the react app because of how browsers now block cookies by default for iframes.

Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite